# Multiple YouTubePlayerView players in one activity

Tags: android

I am trying to have two YouTubePlayerViews on top of each other. They both show up, but only one seems to cue any videos. The first one (youTubeView1) is just black. No errors. 
i read that YouTube Android Player SDK enforcing a one-video-at-a-time limitation, but i can not change it.
Any idea please?

Comment: Works as designed due to enforcement of one-video-at-a-time..

Comment: how can i change one-video-at-a-time